# Sending concatenated query to SQL Server database from Visual Foxpro

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-foxpro

I am using Visual Foxpro 9 with SQL Server as back-end. I am executing this query to update an existing column value with a unicode text:

```
UPDATE <table> SET fname = "N('" + hexchr + "')"
```

The problem is Foxpro is storing string as:

N(0945;0987;)

whereas when the same command is run via SQL Server management studio, the string is stored as actual devnagari font.

How to make Foxpro execute the above query with the N?

Comment: Ever heard of SQL injection? String concatenation of SQL is generally a bad idea...

Comment: Not a concern as of now.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried working with Unicode and feeding SQL-Server... However, with respect to helping prevent SQL-Injection, in VFP, when using SQL-Passthrough (SQLConnect(), SQLExec(), etc), If you write your query with "?" place-holder, it will look at the VARIABLE from within VFP... such as

```
myField = 0x123  && or whatever hex value... VFP leading with 0x implies hex
myKey = "whatever"

cSQLCmd = "update SomeTable set Field1 = ?myField where SomeKey = ?myKey"
nSQLHandle = sqlconnect( YourConnectionStringInfo )
SQLExec( nSQLHandle, cSQLCmd )
sqldisconnect( nSQLHandle )
```

VFP will handle the ? parameters for you by their respective found variable names that are available.   Now, all that being said, VFP was only based on 32 bit, and don't believe it recognizes "unicode" values.  What you may need to do is create a stored procedure in SQL that accepts two hex value (or whatever), and call that and pass it in as so required.